# Flow chart arrow in "Diamond"

Tags: arrows, flow-charts

I have this;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{b} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, node distance=1cm, text     width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, thick]
\tikzstyle{h} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, node distance=3cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, thick]

\tikzstyle{pregunta} = [diamond, draw, fill=yellow!20, node distance=1cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1em, thick,inner sep=0pt]

\tikzstyle{salir} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, node distance=1cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, thick, inner sep=0pt]

\tikzstyle{multi} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, node distance=1cm, text width=15em, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, thick,inner sep=5pt]

\tikzstyle{reiniciar} = [rectangle, draw, fill=brown!20, node distance=1cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, thick, inner sep=0pt]


\tikzstyle{c} = [rectangle, draw, inner sep=0.5cm, dashed]
\tikzstyle{l} = [draw, -latex',thick]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \node [h] (a) {};
    \node [pregunta, below=of a] (b) {};
    \node [b, below=of b,xshift=-3cm,yshift=1.5cm] (c) {};
    \node [b, below=of c,yshift=-1cm,xshift=3cm] (d) {};
    \node [pregunta, below=of d,yshift=0.5cm] (e) {};
    \node [salir, below=of e] (f) {};


    \node [multi, below=of b,xshift=4cm,yshift=1.5cm] (g) { };

    \node [reiniciar, left=of e,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=-1cm] (h) {};  

    \draw [l] (a) -- (b);
    \draw [l] (b)-|(c)node [anchor=north, yshift=+2.5cm] {};
    \draw [l] (b)-|(g)node [anchor=north, yshift=+3.2cm] {};
    \draw [l] (e)--(f)node [anchor=west, yshift=1cm] {};
    \draw [l] (d)--(e);
    \draw [l] (e)-|(h);
    %\draw [l] (h)|-(b);HERE!


    \draw [dashed,thick] (c) |- (d) node [midway,fill=white] {hello};
    \draw [dashed,thick] (g) |- (d) node [midway,fill=white] {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want this, arrow to the top off Diamond:

[image]

How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this to your code:

```
\node [xshift=-0.5cm] at (h) (y) {};
\node [yshift= 1cm] at (b) (z) {};

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw [l,red,ultra thick] (y) |- (z);
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

I had to use `pgfonlayer` to draw the arrow behind the `reiniciar` node.

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{b} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, node distance=1cm, text     width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, thick]
\tikzstyle{h} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, node distance=3cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em, thick]

\tikzstyle{pregunta} = [diamond, draw, fill=yellow!20, node distance=1cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1em, thick,inner sep=0pt]

\tikzstyle{salir} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, node distance=1cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, thick, inner sep=0pt]

\tikzstyle{multi} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, node distance=1cm, text width=15em, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, thick,inner sep=5pt]

\tikzstyle{reiniciar} = [rectangle, draw, fill=brown!20, node distance=1cm, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, thick, inner sep=0pt]


\tikzstyle{c} = [rectangle, draw, inner sep=0.5cm, dashed]
\tikzstyle{l} = [draw, -latex',thick]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \node [h] (a) {};
    \node [pregunta, below=of a] (b) {};
    \node [b, below=of b,xshift=-3cm,yshift=1.5cm] (c) {};
    \node [b, below=of c,yshift=-1cm,xshift=3cm] (d) {};
    \node [pregunta, below=of d,yshift=0.5cm] (e) {};
    \node [salir, below=of e] (f) {};

    \node [multi, below=of b,xshift=4cm,yshift=1.5cm] (g) { };

    \node [reiniciar, left=of e,yshift=1.5cm,xshift=-1cm] (h) {};  

    \draw [l] (a) -- (b);
    \draw [l] (b)-|(c)node [anchor=north, yshift=+2.5cm] {};
    \draw [l] (b)-|(g)node [anchor=north, yshift=+3.2cm] {};
    \draw [l] (e)--(f)node [anchor=west, yshift=1cm] {};
    \draw [l] (d)--(e);
    \draw [l] (e)-|(h);

    \node [xshift=-0.5cm] at (h) (y) {};
    \node [yshift= 1cm] at (b) (z) {};
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \draw [l,red,ultra thick] (y) |- (z);
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \draw [dashed,thick] (c) |- (d) node [midway,fill=white] {hello};
    \draw [dashed,thick] (g) |- (d) node [midway,fill=white] {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

mostly off-topic, but with more correct code syntax and clean code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, fit, positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{FC/.style = {% FC as FlowChart
   node distance = 8 mm and 6 mm,
     base/.style = {draw, thick, rounded corners, align=center},
        b/.style = {base, fill=blue!20,  text width=6em, minimum height=4em},
        h/.style = {base, fill=green!20, text width=6em, minimum height=4em},
 pregunta/.style = {base, diamond, fill=yellow!20, text width=6em, inner sep=0pt},
    salir/.style = {base, fill=red!20,   text width=6em, minimum height=2em, inner sep=0pt},
    multi/.style = {base, fill=blue!20,  text width=15em,minimum height=2em, inner sep=5pt},
reiniciar/.style = {base, fill=brown!20, text width=6em, minimum height=2em, inner sep=0pt},
        c/.style = {base, inner sep=0.5cm, dashed},
        l/.style = {draw, -latex', thick}
                    }
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FC, auto]
    \node [h] (a) {};
    \node [pregunta, below=of a] (b) {};
    \node [b, below left=of b]   (c) {};
    \node [multi, below right=of b]  (d) {};
    \node [b, below=of b |- c.south] (e) {};
    \node [pregunta, below=of e] (f) {};
    \node [salir, below=of f]    (g) {};
    \node [reiniciar, left=of c |- e] (h) {};
    %
    \draw [l]   (a) edge  (b)
                (e) edge node {no}  (f)
                (f) edge node {yes?}  (g);
    \draw [l]   (b) -| (c) node [above right,midway] {x};
    \draw [l]   (b) -| (d) node [above  left,midway] {y};
    \draw [l,dashed]   (c) |- (e) node [below right,midway] {xxx};
    \draw [l,dashed]   (d) |- (e) node [below  left,midway] {yyy};
    \draw [l]   (f) -| (h) node [below right,midway] {no};
    \draw [l,red]      (h) |- ($(a.south)!0.5!(b.north)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Zarco, my code was messy. If it is not ordered, it takes many hours. Another thing, can you explain yourself about the meaning of : `l/.style = {draw, -latex', thick}` And for example, if I want to put the arrow on top of 'y', How can i do?: `\draw [l,red]  (h) |- (a.north UP 0.25cm) -| (d.north UP 0.25cm)`?? Thanks Zarko

Comment: @Solid, i took names of styles from you. i only change recent (correct) syntax, meanwhile yours is obsolete.  arrows over `y` is matter of math notation: `$\vec{y}$`, if you mean this. if you like to have edge labels of below them, than you need to change node position from `above` to `below` .